# Save search and replace queries for future use

Tags: search

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way or recommend a method to save often use search and replace queries for future use after emacs restarts?

Comment: `(savehist-mode 1)` makes your minibuffer history lists persist between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are asking how to save search ***queries*** then you need only save the variable **`search-ring`** or **`regexp-search-ring`** (or both) -- those are your search histories.  You can use option **`savehist-additional-variables`** for that (and turn on `savehist-mode`: `(savehist-mode 1)`.
- If you are how to save the ***results*** of searches then this is one way: Use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) and search using [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview). With that, the search hits for a given search query are completion candidates. And you can save the current completion candidates anytime and restore them later.  You can [save them persistently](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions) or just [for the current session](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets) (e.g. across any number of different actions, including different searches).